# Can vector fields be used to construct diffeomorphisms of the 2-sphere?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

For some reason, today I want to understand better the group of diffeomorphisms of the 2-sphere, $S^2$.

After a few minutes I found this result by [Smale in 1958](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2033664).

> The space $\Omega$ of all orientation-preserving $C^\infty$
>   diffeomorphisms of $S^2$ has a strong deformation retract [to] the
>   rotation group $SO(3)$.

It sounds like any invertible, differentiable map $f:S^2 \to S^2$ can be "smoothed" to a 3D rotation of a certain angle $\theta$ around a certain axis $\vec{k}$.

Smale gives an explicit retraction from $f \in C^\infty(S^2)$ to the rotation

$$\begin{array}{rcc} f(x_0) &\mapsto& x_0 \\
df(e_1) &\mapsto& e_1 \\
df(e_2) &\mapsto& e_2 \end{array}$$

There seems to be [an alternative proof](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/937notes/937Lecture24.pdf) in some topology notes. Jacob Lurie describes a fibration over the space of all conformal structures on the 2-sphere

\[ \mathrm{Diff}_{\mathrm{Conf}}(S^2) \to \mathrm{Diff}(S^2)
\to \mathrm{Conf}(S^2) \]

and another diagram related to the existence of [isothermal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_pictures):

\[  \begin{array}{ccccc}
SO(2) & \to & SO(3) & \to & S^2 \\ 
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
Aut(\mathbb{C}) & \to & \mathrm{Diff}_{\mathrm{Conf}}(S^2) & \to & S^2 
\end{array} \]

These discussions of the diffeomorphism group 2-sphere were not very concrete, but after writing this I have answered much of my own questions...

I suppose can could get conformal structures like $e^{f(z)} dz\, d\overline{z}$.

---

What kind of information did we lose after these reductions?
What are some elements of $\mathrm{Diff}(S^2)$ you can build?

**REMARK**:
One comment suggested I use vector fields to construct my diffeomorphism.  If I have a smooth section of the tangent bundle $T(S^2)$ can it be "integrated" to a diffeomorphism of $S^2 \to S^2$ ?

Comment: The Smale argument is very explicit and direct, it's not clear to me the alternative argument you propsoe is  streamlined in any sense.  It does bring in more intermediate notions, so if that's your concern I suppose it's helpful.  But Smale's proof requires far less prerequisites, so in that sense it's much simpler.

Comment: Regarding your question, it seems to me the clear answer is you lose essentially all information about the group structure.  Smale's theorem is only about the homotopy-type of $Diff(S^2)$, it says little about $Diff(S^2)$ as a topological group.  It depends on what you mean by "exotic" but diffeomorphisms with only one fixed point might qualify, as they are not conjugate to linear maps.

Comment: If you try to phrase the question in mathematical terms, it would be easier to answer, and most likely you will answer it yourself in the process.

Comment: I like Smale's proof.  I think it is **easier**.  Also I've never seen a homotopy of an infinite dimensional space like $Diff(S^2) \to SO(3)$.

Comment: Ryan, a translation of $\mathbb R^2$ extends to a diffeomorphism of $S^2$ with one fixed point; it is hardly exotic.

Comment: For your final question, I wonder what you mean by an element $f \in Diff(S^2)$ "representing" the identity. If what you mean is that the image of $f$ under the homotopy equivalence to $SO(3)$ is the identity, from any homotopy equivalence $Diff(S^2) \to SO(3)$ you can produce a different one that takes $f$ to the identity.

Comment: How exotic do you find conformal self-maps of the Riemann sphere? Say, $z\mapsto z+1$?

Comment: Since $Diff^+(S^2)$ is a simple group, you cannot expect more than homotopy answers.

Comment: I guess I want an example of a diffeomorphism of $S^2$ that isn't of the form $az+b$ or a rotation in $SO(3)$.

Comment: @John: then take the flow of a random vector field.

Comment: @Igor: not from the perspective of $SO(3)$.  With no functional definition of exotic in this context, I suppose there's no real point of talking about things being exotic or not.

Comment: I've voted to close, this question is too vague.

Comment: @Ryan.  If I have section of the tangent bundle $T(S^2)$ can it be "integrated" to a diffeomorphism of $S^2 \to S^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is the existence and uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations.  Smale uses it in his proof.

Comment: Can't solutions blow up?

Comment: @John, the sphere is compact, so vector fields on it are complete. This is explained in the usual textbooks; Lee's book on smooth manifolds, for example.

Comment: See survey "Diffeomorphism groups of compact manifolds" Journal of Mathematical Sciences
2007, (146) Issue 6, pp 6213-6312, by Smolentsev.
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10958-007-0471-0

Answer (score 3):

Some more exotic elements or even subgroups of exotic elements:
The following groups extend to subgroups of $Diff(S^2)$ which fix the north pole via stereographic projection:

- $Diff_{\mathcal B}(\mathbb R^2) = \lbrace Id + f: f\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)^2, \det(df)\ge\epsilon>0\rbrace$ where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$ is the space of functions which are globally bounded, in each partial derivative separately (called $\mathcal D_{L^\infty}$ by L. Schwartz)
- $Diff_{H^\infty}(\mathbb R^2)  = \lbrace Id + f: f\in H^\infty(\mathbb R^2)^2, \det(I_2+df)>0\rbrace$ where $H^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ is the intersection of all Sobolev spaces $H^k$ for $k\ge 0$.
- $Diff_{\mathcal S}(\mathbb R^2) = \lbrace Id + f: f\in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^2)^2, \det(I_2+df)>0\rbrace$ where $\mathcal S$ is the Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions.
- $Diff_{c}(\mathbb R^2) = \lbrace Id + f: f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^2)^2, \det(\mathbb I_2+df)>0\rbrace$ where $C^\infty_c$ are the smooth functions with compact support.

Note that all these diffeomorphism groups are normal subgroups in each larger one, the largest being $Diff_{\mathcal B}$.

> Edit:

The question changed when I wrote the above answer.
The question now asks which element of $Diff(S^2)$ you get by integrating vector fields:

Answer: if you use time-dependent vector fields, you get each orientation preserving diffeomorphism. 
With autonomous vector fields you only get a connected subset which does not cover any neighborhood of the identity. The strongest result is due to Grabowski: There exists a smooth curve of diffeomorphisms in $Diff(S^2)$ starting at the identity, injective, such that the elements of the curve form free generators for a free group (with uncountably many generators) such that no element of this free group can be embedded into a flow.  This free group is smoothly path-connected to the identity (slide the generators along the curve).

> Second edit:

@Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: The paper is the following.

- MR0974661 (90b:58031) 
  Grabowski, Janusz(PL-WASW)
  Free subgroups of diffeomorphism groups. 
  Fund. Math. 131 (1988), no. 2, 103–121.

The method consists of piecing together 1-dimensional diffeomorphisms which do not embed into a flow (published first by Nancy Kopell) in an intricate combinatorial way.

@John Mangual: Generators? On the circle trigonometric polynomial vector fields are dense in the Lie algebra  --- probabaly this is what you mean if you talk about generators.
On $S^2$ one can expand vector fields with respect to the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian (eigenvalues are multiple since the Laplacian has a large symmetry group $O(3)$). Finte sums are then dense.

Comment: What's the idea behind the proof that such a huge number of diffeos generate a free group?

Comment: can you write a set of generators for $Diff(S^2)$ the way you can for $Diff(S^1)$ ?